# redis-nodejs pub sub 2 channel at the same time

Tags: node.js, redis

I have 2 channel pub/sub, assume channel 1 and channel 2. When I pub to 2 channel by order 1 -> 2. I expect sub client will get data by order 1,2.
But sometime I get 2->1. I know it is asynchorous. 
How can I get data by order 1 -> 2?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code? Are you saying that you do `redis.publish('channel1', message)` followed by `redis.publish('channel2', message)` but receive the messages in the `message` event in a different order?

Comment: srr, it 's my fault. It is in order now. ty